# How to read file line by line storing every word in seperate string? Python

Tags: python, string, store, readline

How do I read a file of data and store everything separated by a space into another string?

If I have, for example, a column with names and a column with the age, like:

```
Anna 23
Tim 12
```

So it should put Anna and Tim into a string name and 23 and 12 into a string age.

Is there something like get in c++?

Answer (score 0):

You can use split() to get a list of words in each line and save the elements of the list to separate strings.
For example

```
"Anna 23".split()
```

results in

```
["Anna", "23"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems like an easy and convienient way!